# boto dynamodb: is there a way to optimize batch writing?

Tags: batch-processing, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I am indexing large amounts of data into DynamoDB and experimenting with batch writing to increase actual throughput (i.e. make indexing faster). Here's a block of code ([**this**](https://gist.github.com/griggheo/2698152) is the original source):

```
def do_batch_write(items,conn,table):
    batch_list = conn.new_batch_write_list()
    batch_list.add_batch(table, puts=items)
    while True:
            response = conn.batch_write_item(batch_list)
            unprocessed = response.get('UnprocessedItems', None)
            if not unprocessed:
                    break
            # identify unprocessed items and retry batch writing
```

I am using boto version 2.8.0. I get an exception if `items` has more than 25 elements. **Is there a way to increase this limit?** Also, I noticed that sometimes, even if `items` is shorter, it cannot process all of them in a single try. But there does not seem to be correlation between how often this happens, or how many elements are left unprocessed after a try, and the original length of `items`. **Is there a way to avoid this and write everything in one try?** Now, the ultimate goal is to make processing faster, not just avoid repeats, so sleeping for a long period of time between successive tries is not an option.

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html):

"The BatchWriteItem operation puts or deletes multiple items in one or more tables. A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests. Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB."

The reason for some not succeeded is probably due to exceeding the provisioned throughput of your table.  Do you have other write operations being performed on the table at the same time?  Have you tried increasing the write throughput on your table to see if more items are processed.

I'm not aware of any way of increasing the limit of 25 items per request but you could try asking on the AWS Forums or through your support channel.

I think the best way to get maximum throughput is to increase the write capacity units as high as you can and to parallelize the batch write operations across several threads or processes.

Comment: I have done some experiments of running multiple indexing jobs on the same machine. This did not increase actual throughput. I think the network my be the bottleneck.

Comment: Have you tried running it on an EC2 instance in the same region as your DynamoDB table?

Comment: Aren't they by default in the same region?

Comment: try to call `boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()['instance-id']` and compare with your `boto.dynamodb.Layer2.layer1.region`

Comment: running `boto.dynamodb.layer2.layer1.region` produced `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'layer1'`

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, there is little to be gained in trying to optimize your write throughput using either batch write or multithreading. Batch write saves a little network time, and multithreading saves close to nothing as the item size limitation is quite low and the bottleneck is very often DDB throttling your request.

So (like it or not) increasing your Write Capacity in DynamoDB is the way to go.

Ah, like garnaat said, latency inside the region is often really different (like from 15ms to 250ms) from inter-region or outside AWS.

Comment: I just switched my code from single writes to batch writes of size 20. Actual throughput went form <= 100 to 400 and can probably go higher. Since I read in a couple of places (including here) that switching to batch writes can only marginally increase t/p, I am not sure whether the speed up is due solely to the batch writes or to me removing some other inefficiencies in the code while making the change. But I did not fiddle with regions at all.

Comment: How much Write Capacity did you provision ? you mean 400 QPS throughput I guess, so if your dynamodb capacity is < 400 you'll probably get throttled requests. Did you have any before ? There is a nice graph for this in the AWS console.

Answer (score 2):

Not only increasing the Write Capacity will make it faster.

if your HASH KEY diversity is poor, then even if you will increase your write capacity, then you can have throughput errors.

throughput errors are depends on your hit map.

example: if your hash key is a number between 1-10, and you have 10 records with hash value 1-10 but 10k records with value 10, then you will have many throughput errors even while increasing your write capacity.